# XMLHttpRequest + submit the Value of the clicked Radiobutton

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, radio-button

I have a question aboud a XMLHttpRequest with Radio Buttons. I need to submit the value for saving it in the DB. I have made a onclick Event to trigger the Value selected.

```
    function ajax_radiobtn(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var rdbid = target.id;
    var rdbval = target.value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'URL';

    //Send
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    var return_data = xhr.responseText;
    document.getElementById("Register").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
    }
    xhr.send(ausgabe);
    document.getElementById("Register").innerHTML = "Reload..";
    }
```

This Request works for all Textfileds an Texareas but not for Radiobuttons. I can trigger the value, but the submitting do not work. Is there someone who can tell me how it works?

```
var url = "URL";
var params = "somevariable=somevalue&anothervariable=anothervalue";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
```

I trye this, maybe this works?

Comment: Does your console show ant errors?

Comment: what is xhr.send(ausgabe);?

Comment: Also you havent set the URL

Comment: The console shows the Error ReferenceError: ajax_radiobtn is not defined xhr.send ist the send function for the displaying of the answere and yes the URL is set. It works for textfileds and textareas.

Comment: var coachingprogramm = document.getElementById("coachingprogramm").value;
var ausgabe = coachingprogramm="+coachingprogramm";

This is how a set the Variable, is this right? And big THX to Joey Pinto for your answere.

Comment: Check for unbalanced brackets, can you post the rest of your javascript code and html possibly in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry this is not possible, i use DB for the Datasettings. It must be a problem with the var definition that is true. But i triggered allready the information needed with:

    var rdbid = target.id;
    var rdbval = target.value;

So i have the ID of the selceted Radiobutton in rdbid and the value in rdbval. But a can not send them to the URL in the correcte way. Can you give me some help?

Comment: Just one question: When i submit the values to the external File with the XMLHttpRequest how should the variable look like?

Comment: ausgabe should be something like "param_a=value_of_a&param_b=value_of_b&param_c=value_of_c"

Comment: Thx Joey Pinto, i try this.

Comment: If i tryed 

var rdbid = target.id;
var rdbval = target.value;
var ausgabe = '"'rdbid + '=' + rdbval + '"';

The Result is; ReferenceError: ajax_radiobtn is not defined AND ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: Please understand there is a syntax error somewhere in your code that us causing this error. Mostly missing brackets. I wont help you now till you fix that

Comment: I did a mistake it works now!!! thak you so much!!! Now i can save the value in the database in the external file.

Comment: var rdbid = target.id;
var rdbval = target.value;
var ausgabe = '"' + rdbid + '=' + rdbval + '"';

Thx @ Joey Pinto, it works!!!

Comment: You dont need the '"' part it doesnt do anything. var ausgabe =rdbid + '=' + rdbval; is enough

Comment: Please accept the solution if it solved your problem

Comment: @ Joey Pinto - Thx for your help it works :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion in the comments revealed that there was a syntax error leading to

```
ReferenceError: ajax_radiobtn is not defined
```

fixing the missing brackets solved the problem for Mr.Robot

Also the data in send() had to be

```
var ausgabe =rdbid + '=' + rdbval;
```